# Python: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to scrape a webpage that contains Japanese characters:

```
import urllib2
import bs4
import time

url = 'http://www.city.sapporo.jp/eisei/tiiki/toban.html'

pagecontent = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pagecontent.read().decode("utf8"))

print(soup.prettify())
print(soup)
```

In some machines the code works fine, and the last two statements print the result successfully.
However, in some machines the last but one statement gives the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 485-496: ordinal not in range(128),
```

and the last statement prints strange squares for all Japanese characters.

Why the same code works differently for two machines? How can I fix this?

Python version 2.6.6

bs4 version: 4.1.0

Comment: You are printing *Unicode data* and Python needs to encode that to match your Python terminal or console encoding. You'll need to fix your terminal to tell Python correctly what codecs it accepts. Currently it tells Python that only ASCII will do. What is the console or terminal you are using?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am using CentOS's default terminal.

Comment: Then set the `LANG` environment variable, see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html.

Answer (score 7):

You need to configure your environment locale correctly; once your locale is set, Python will pick it up automatically when printing to a terminal.

Check your locale with the `locale` command:

```sh
$ locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Note the `.UTF-8` in my locale settings; it tells programs running in the terminal that my terminal uses the UTF-8 codec, one that supports all of Unicode.

You can set all of your locale in one step with the `LANG` environment variable:

```sh
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

for a US locale (how dates and numbers are printed) with the UTF-8 codec. To be precise, the `LC_CTYPE` setting is used for the output codec, which in turn defaults to the `LANG` value.

Also see the *very comprehensive* [UTF-8 and Unicode FAQ for Unix/Linux](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html).

Comment: I just checked my machine that runs Mac OSX and can correctly print out the result, which has 'locale' set as:                        LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: @shapeare: yes, because the output encoding is taken from `LC_CTYPE`.

Comment: I have added a line `export LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"` in `~/.bashrc`, and then run `source ~/.bashrc` so it takes effect. But the problem still exists, still saying `'ascii' codec can't encode characters`

Comment: @shapeare: The traceback is still pointing to the `print` statement? What does `import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding` show Python detected?

Comment: The traceback still points to print statement. The sys.stdout.encoding prints out `ANSI_X3.4-1968`

Comment: @shapeare: that clearly is not the right codec you configured. What does `locale` (in the shell) say `LC_CTYPE` is set to? In Python `import os; print os.environ.get('LC_CTYPE'), os.environ.get('LANG')` is interesting too, as is `import locale; print locale.getdefaultlocale()`.

Comment: `os.environ.get('LC_CTYPE')` prints out `UTF-8`, `os.environ.get('LANG')` prints out `ja-JP.UTF-8` and `locale.getdefaultlocale()` raises an error `unknown locale: UTF-8`

Comment: @shapeare: interesting, same symptoms as https://github.com/iElectric/almir/issues/59

Comment: @shapeare: the error indicates that your `_locale.so` module wasn't being loaded; what does `import _locale` do for you? Without that module Python has no UTF-8 codec to encode.

Comment: Now I have changed to use `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. The error at the print statement has disappeared, but it still prints squares for each Japanese character. Adding `import _locale` to my code doesn't introduce any error.

Comment: @shapeare: is your terminal actually set up for UTF-8 as well? Telling Python to print UTF-8 bytes is just one step in the chain.